# Regex, find a match when there are two patterns, C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following two patterns and need to find a match if either or is found in a string and then move onto the next match.

for one pattern i've been using

```
 MatchCollection m0 = Regex.Matches(file, @"<ul class=""Information"">[\s\n\t.]+<img src=""http://test/images/I/test.gif"">",
                   RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

then looping through the matches and extracting the details I need

The second pattern I need is

```
MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(file, @"<ul class=""Information"">[\s\n\t.]+ <a href=""http://www.test.com/test/""\w+",
                   RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Is it possible in regex to combine these into one search, using an OR for example?

Comment: Why is it so tempting to use regular expressions for parsing HTML?

Comment: I suppose I was initially just looking to extract 1 value and using regular expression worked fast and easily but now the requirements have changed, perhaps parsing would be an easier route?

Comment: @dtb: While I agree that in **most cases**, it's not prudent to use Regex, it works for very simple cases quite well. Sometimes the HTMLAgilityPack is overkill for something simple that can be solved very quickly with a simple regex.

Comment: @Aren but a regular expression is a overkill too, since it's a whole engine.

Comment: @Eder: It may be, but it's something people understand fairly well. Or at least the concept of a regular expression. It may be worthwhile to point out there's probably a different/better way to do it, but that's not his question, and shaming him for thinking this way is not constructive, and that's why I called out dtb's comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Disclaimer

For the haters out there, this isn't neccesarily a Parsing HTML with Regex Question. The root of his question is he's looking for the Disjunction functionality in a regex.

### Solution

While @dtb may be right about regex with html, for simple cases (small inputs & simple patterns) it's not neccesarily a bad idea if you know when to use it.

This is a simple solution in regex.

```
string pattern = @"<ul class=""Information"">[\s\n\t.]+" +
                 @"(?:<img src=""http://test/images/I/test.gif"">|" +
                 @"<a href=""http://www.test.com/test/""\w+)";

MatchCollection m0 = Regex.Matches(file, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

What's been done here @Paul is we've taken the two trailing components of your matches and put them into a non-capturing group: `(?:  )`. This makes sure it won't mess with your capture groups, but you're welcome to capture it if you need to.

From here we use the OR operator `|` to split the group into capturing either one or the other.

```
(?:<img src="http://test/images/I/test.gif">|<a href="http://www.test.com/test/"\w+)
```

This is the resulting pattern match for the 2nd part.

*Note: If you are doing this more than once in a while (i.e. a loop) you should compile your regex, it'll execute faster.*